# Distances between vertices in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Prove $$d(x,z)\le d(x,y)+d(y,z)$$
I did attempt a proof, but I'm not really sure if the reasoning is sound, and I also want to know alternative answers.

Let P1=(x,...,y) and P2=(y,...,z)

(1)P1 and P2 have no vertices other than y in common.
Then P=(x,...,y,...,z) obtained by adjoining P2 to P1 is a path, since P1 and P2 are themselves paths and have no vertices in common except y. Moreover, the length of P is $d(x,y)+d(y,z)$
If there is a path from x to z with a shorter length, then $d(x,z)\le d(x,y)+d(y,z)$. If not, then

(the length of the shortest path from x to z) (i.e. $d(x,z)$) $= d(x,y)+d(y,z)$.

(2)P1 and P2 have some vertices in common. Let the first vertex that appears in both graphs be k. So P1=(x,...,k,...,y) and P2=(y,...,k,s,..,z). Construct P=(x,...,k,s,...,z). Then P has no repeated vertices and have length strictly less than $d(x,y)+d(y,z)$. If there is a path from x to z with a shorter length, then $d(x,z)\lt d(x,y)+d(y,z)$. If not, then P is the shortest path from x to z and the same inequality holds.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, no cases are necessary. Remember that $d(x,z)$ is the length of the *shortest* path from $x$ to $z$.

Given a shortest path from $x$ to $y$, and a shortest path from $y$ to $z$, you can concatenate them to get a path of length $d(x,y) + d(y,z)$ from $x$ to $z$. It might not be the shortest path, but it does establish your inequality.

Comment: this is essentially just semantics, the argument is the same